Regex that stop matching till new line
I want regex that match words 'terimakasih' and stop when encounter comma,period or newline
here's my regex when i try it :
\bterimakasih\b[^,.]*[\n,.]
but when i try it in this text :

halo zulhelmi, terimakasih atas pertanyaan anda
keluhan yang anda sampaikan di atas bisa disebabkan oleh beberapa penyebab, yaitu :
terjadi perubahan status refraksi pada salah satu atau kedua mata sehingga kacamata yang digunakan tidak tepat untuk mengoreksi tajam penglihatan
mata mengalami kelelahan setelah digunakan dalam jangka waktu lama tanpa disertai waktu istirahat yang cukupkondisi ini juga dipengaruhi oleh faktor pencahayaan, baik dari lingkungan sekitar ataupun dari layar komputer dan smartphone sendiri, juga faktor kelembaban udara, di mana udara kering (seperti lingkungan ber-ac) meningkatkan potensi terjadinya mata lelah
penanganan yang bisa anda lakukan di rumah :
atur pencahayaan dari layar komputer ataupun smartphone
pastikan lingkungan sekitar cukup terang, namun tidak menyilaukan mata
posisikan layar komputer atau smartphone sekitar 30-50 cm
istirahatkan mata secara berkala, misalnya dengan berpaling menatap lokasi yang jauh (sekitar 6 meter)
jangan lupa berkedip, terutama ketika beraktivitas di ruangan ber-ac agar mata tidak kering
bila dengan menerapkan anjuran di atas keluhan tidak berkurang, ada baiknya memastikan penyebab keluhan anda ke dokter spesialis mata. dokter akan melakukan pemeriksaan tajam penglihatan sekaligus menentukan lensa kacamata koreksi, juga memastikan kondisi kesehatan mata anda menggunakan alat khusus, misalnya slit lamp untuk mengevaluasi bagian luar mata dan oftalmoskopi untuk memeriksa bagian dalam mata. penanganan ditentukan setelah penyebab yang mendasari dipastikan.
demikian, semoga bermanfaat
dr. lili

it match :

terimakasih atas pertanyaan anda
keluhan yang anda sampaikan di atas bisa disebabkan oleh beberapa penyebab,

i just want :

terimakasih atas pertanyaan anda

so it's stop in new line
I already try \n and \r but it doesn't stop

But your [^,.] matches newlines, add it there, ie. [^,.\n]
